Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и» в данном предложении? (2)
Как я уже говорил, к нам периодически прибывают беженцы(,) и не все они из Северной Африки.
Смотрела правила, там написано, что если есть общая придаточная часть, то запятая не нужна. "Как я уже говорил" — это общее придаточное предложение? Поясню, что персонаж говорил и о прибытии беженцев, и о том, откуда они прибыли.

Правильно:
Как я уже говорил, к нам периодически прибывают беженцы, и не все они из Северной Африки.
Пояснение
С уже данным решение я соглашусь, но грамматику нужно уточнить.

Это тема общего элемента в ССП, когда запятая перед И может не ставиться.

Как я уже говорил — вводное предложение со значением источника информации, но является ли оно общим элементом для двух предложений в составе ССП?
Примечание. Даже если его считать общим придаточным, то это придаточное соответствия, но не определительное.

Без контекста сложно сказать, но в этой теме есть еще одно важное условие: простые предложения в составе ССП должны быть однородными, то есть независимыми и не связанными какими-либо отношениями.

А это условие не соблюдается. Дело в том, что в ССП при наличии союза И возможны различные отношения (кроме однородных),  в грамматике указано 8 видов. В нашем случае это соединительно-распространительное значение: вторая часть добавляет сведения к первой части, что видно по структуре и лексике (беженцы — они).

Другими словами, это не присоединительные, а распространительные отношения. Союз И в качестве присоединительного используется в несколько других конструкциях. Розенталь § 24. Присоединительные конструкции. Например: Рудин заговорил о самолюбии, и  очень дельно заговорил.  Это однородные сказуемые в значении присоединения.


Большое спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Интуитивно понимала, что подлежащее "они" (т.е. беженцы) указывает на связь с предыдущим предложением, но не могла найти соответствующее обоснование. Смотрела параграф о присоединительных отношениях, но там не нашла подобных конструкций. Дело, оказывается, в том, что данные предложения не являются однородными.

Моя версия:
Как я уже говорил, к нам периодически прибывают беженцы, и не все они из Северной Африки.
и не все они из Северной Африки - присоединительный член предложения, введённый при помощи союза И. В таких случаях ставится запятая или тире.
ПАС
Передавая им эти сведения, он поступил нехорошо, и  знал это.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю. У нас СПП с вводным предложением "Как я уже говорил", главной частью "к нам периодически прибывают беженцы" и присоединительным предложением "не все они из Северной Африки". Ну, а предложение "Как я уже говорил" не является придаточным так как от главного предложения к нему невозможно задать вопрос.  [https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/737-221_pridatochnye_opredelitelnye.html](Разделы 2.2.1-2.3.8)

Я тоже понимаю именно так.

Спасибо за ответ. "Как я уже говорил" - действительно вводное предложение, а не придаточное, как я сначала подумала. Но это вводное предложение является общим и для "к нам периодически прибывают беженцы", и для "не все они из Северной Африки". Герой и об этом говорил тоже. То, что имеется общая часть, и смутило. А в предложении "Передавая эти сведения, он поступил нехорошо, и знал это" такой общей части нет.
